# Remove a div after 5s

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX form:

```
function form(){

        var icao = document.getElementById('icao').value;
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var weightempty = document.getElementById('weightempty').value;
        var weightfull = document.getElementById('weightfull').value;
        var cargofull = document.getElementById('cargofull').value;
        var cruisespeed = document.getElementById('cruisespeed').value;
        var range = document.getElementById('range').value;
        var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var firstclassseats = document.getElementById('firstclassseats').value;
        var businessclassseats = document.getElementById('businessclassseats').value;
        var economyclassseats = document.getElementById('economyclassseats').value;
        ajax.open("POST","new_aircraft_process.php",true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(ajax.readyState==4)
            {
            var respuesta=ajax.responseText;


            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=ajax.responseText;
            $("#newaircraftdialog").dialog('close');


            refreshTable(function(){$("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');});
            }
        }
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send("icao="+icao+"&name="+name+"&weightempty="+weightempty+"&weightfull="+weightfull+"&cargofull="+cargofull+"&cruisespeed="+cruisespeed+"&range="+range+"&price="+price+"&firstclassseats="+firstclassseats+"&businessclassseats="+businessclassseats+"&economyclassseats="+economyclassseats);
    $("#loadingdialog").dialog('open');
    }
```

I want is  when the result is displayed (it is a text that says "Successful Form") in the result div is it visible only for 5 seconds and then disappears. I have found various ways, but do not want to delete the div. Because if I want to make the form another time the result of this will have to show again in the div and disappear after 5 seconds after.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.myDiv').fadeIn(); // Show the div to start.
// All your other code here.
setTimeout(function() { $('.myDiv').fadeOut() }, 5000); // hide the div after we're done
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put it in an anonymous function. It should work now.

Comment: I have a problem with this. When I want to do another time the dialog without refresh the page dont works!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Please explain further.

Comment: If the OP wants to show the div again later, "remove" is the wrong method. He should either detach or hide it.

Comment: The title of the OP is "Remove a div after 5s", so I removed a div after five seconds. I prefer `$('.myDiv).fadeOut()` though

Comment: Yeah! I do the form, ALL ok, the div was removed. But when I want to do the form other time without reload the page the AJAX script dont find the result div to put the result.

Comment: Then, you'll need to do what I say in the question. I'll update it shortly.

Comment: @DavidHarris, there is more to a question than the title.

Comment: Now, all the form its fine I can do it all times. But the messege in the div only shows first time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delay()`

```
$('divtoremove').delay(5000).fadeOut('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the div and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) it later when the form is resubmitted.

```
ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(ajax.readyState==4)
    {
        var respuesta=ajax.responseText;


        var $result = $('#result');
        $result.html(ajax.responseText);
        $result.show();
        setTimeout(function() { $result.hide() }, 5000);
        $("#newaircraftdialog").dialog('close');


        refreshTable(function(){$("#loadingdialog").dialog('close');});
    }
}
```

You can also use [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and reattach it to the DOM later.

Comment: The same problem that other answer: I do the form, ALL ok, the div was removed. But when I want to do the form other time without reload the page the AJAX script dont find the result div to put the result.

Comment: @user1972864, I updated the code to both show and hide your div. Try that and let me know if it works.